# How to know whether the Register Email is verified or not in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

```
onSubmit(formData) {
if(formData.valid) {
  console.log(formData.value);
  this.af.auth.createUser({
    email: formData.value.email,
    password: formData.value.password
  }).then(
    authState => {
    authState.auth.sendEmailVerification();
    this.router.navigate(['/login'])
  }).catch(
    (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    this.error = err;
  })
}
}
```

In Firebase, I set the `SendEmailVerfication` like the code above, and the email could send normally.However, in my app, there is no difference between the user who does not click the verification email with those clicked, how to make a difference?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to the documentation, the [`User`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User) object contains an [`emailVerified`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#emailVerified) property.

So the user to which the [`signInWithEmailAndPassword`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithEmailAndPassword) method's promise resolves - or the user that is passed to the [`onAuthStateChanged`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged) method's callback - can be inspected and the value of `emailVerified` can be checked.

Answer (score 20):

You can use `firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified`

This will return `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 5):

***- If you are already loggedIn below solutions can help you to check email verified status.***

**1)** The recommended way to get the current user is by setting an observer on the Auth object:

```
 firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
      if(authUser.user.emailVerified){ //This will return true or false
        console.log('email is verified')
       }else{
           console.log('email not verified')
       }
    })
```

**2)** You can also get the currently signed-in user by using the currentUser property.

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if (user.emailVerified) {
  // email is verified.
} else {
  // email is not verified.
}
```

***- If you are not loggedIn then please try below solution.***

```
     firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password ).then(authUser => {

      if(authUser.user.emailVerified){ //This will return true or false
       console.log('email is verified')
      }else{
        console.log('email not verified')
      }
      }).catch(function(error) {

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add an attribute at firebase database for the state of your user verification [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler)

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer for newer versions

If the user is already signed In and you want to check if the email is verified you have to reload the current users data since its cached.

```
auth.currentUser.reload()
```

Once that is done you can easily check if the email is verified

```
auth.currentUser.emailVerified //returns boolean
```